# how to load the image from ListView in a new Activity using putExtras?

Tags: android, image, listview, fullscreen

The images in `ListView` are small and i would like to show the clicked image in original size in a new `Activity`

Here is my code, but how can I use `putExtras` to get the image in `Activity` 2 ?

```
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View row, int position, long id) {

            ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            int images = imageview.getId();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            Activity_Full_Screen.class);
            i.putExtra("pos", position);
            startActivity(i);

        }

    });
```

Activity2 :

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.Activity_Full_Screen);


    ImageView images = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_msg_full_screen);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int pic =intent.getIntExtra("pos", 0);
    images.setImageResource(pic);


}
```

I get this error :

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxxxxxx.Activity_Full_Screen}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x2
```

my Activities are like this Picture : [image: Example]

I try to get the image in Activity2 like that :

```
public class Activity_Full_Screen extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imageView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen);


    ImageView images = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_full_screen);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int pic =intent.getIntExtra("pos", 0);
    images.setImageResource(pic);


    }
    }
```

xml :

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity__full_screen"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.testing.test1.Main">

<ImageView
    android:background="@drawable/img_empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageview_full_screen"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

i can get the image link easy if i change the getItem from id to img but the problem i can not change it, because i need the id too for other functions [image: Solution 1 here but not OK]

Comment: I will suggest re-downloading the image in the other activity, since what you show in the list are thumbnails which supposedly are much smaller.

Comment: Do you have a custom listView Adaptor? if yes, please post the adaptor code.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the extra in the `Intent` with

```
Show_Full_Screen.putExtra("url", url);
```

then retrieving in the new `Activity` with

```
String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url")
```

Inside getView you should be handling each item of you list.
something like

```
final Item item = listOfItems.get(position);
Picasso.with(Main.this).load(item.getUrl()).into(img);
img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent Show_Full_Screen = new Intent(Main.this,   Activity_Full_Screen.class);
            Show_Full_Screen.putExtra("url", item.getUrl());
            startActivity(Show_Full_Screen);

        }
    });
```

Comment: but I have to get url from Listview via position. how to get the  " url  "?

Comment: I use a bit different way, i have changed the code, pls check the error :
`Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxxxxxx.Activity_Full_Screen}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x2`

Comment: something is wrong in one of your resources in the new activity.   It could be the xml.   Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: you are storing the position of the item in the extra.   when you get this position in the new activity, you try and use Picasso to add the position to ImageView.  which essentially means you are loading images.setImageResource(0);  , 0 is not a valid resource

Comment: fixed it easy with : `String img_link = String.valueOf(getItem(position));`
but I should not change the override methode from id to img, because i need the id for other functions :
`@Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return        ListItemForAdapter.get(position).id;  }`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make an ArrayList of your dataType. For you purpose it can be named `Data`.
`List<Data> list = new ArrayList<>();`
where Data class contains

```
private url imgUrl;
private String textOne;
private String textTwo;
```

Now add your value to the `list`. 
Data list

`String[] urlArray;
String[] stringArrayOne; 
String[] stringArrayTwo;`.

Now add them to list them.

```
for(int i=0; i<image_res.length(); i++){
        Data.add(image_res[i], stringArrayOne[i], stringArrayTwo[i]);
    }
```

add the adaptor to your `listView`

```
listView.setAdapter(objAdapter);
```

now add onClickListener to the `listView`

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Data singleData = list.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity_Full_Screen.class);
            intent.putExtra("url", singleData.singleData());
            startActivity(intent);
     }
    });
```

Get the `url` value by `getIntent().getStringExtra("url")` from your `Activity_Full_Screen` class.

for the additional resource, you can see [Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: i fixed the problem but i get an other problem, because i have changed the overide methode of getItem from id to img  like that :
`@Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return        ListItemForAdapter.get(position).img;  }`
and I get the img link like that :

`String img_link = String.valueOf(getItem(position));`

but the problem , i nedd the id for other function too :
`@Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return        ListItemForAdapter.get(position).id;  }
`

Answer (score 0):

I try to get the image in Activity2 like that :

```
public class Activity_Full_Screen extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imageView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen);


    ImageView images = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_full_screen);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int pic =intent.getIntExtra("pos", 0);
    images.setImageResource(pic);


}
```

}

I have fixed the problem now. I could get all what i need via getView and after that i can save the strings in a class or send them in intent :

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup   viewGroup) {

 String img_link =ListItemForAdapter.get(position).img;
 String id =ListItemForAdapter.get(position).id;
// after that i can put the img-link in Activity2 into OnCreate, i get it from class or from intent.
```

Thanks